# Compilation problem with WinEdt

Tags: errors, compiling, winedt

I am writing my PhD thesis with WinEdt and recently started to see the following error message. I didn't edit any settings nor change anything in the configurations. Can anybody help?

```
Runaway argument?
{\blx@citepunct@i {\blxcitecmd {footcite}}{{}}{345{masaryk.1965a}. Alle\ETC 
! Paragraph ended before \blx@xsantitizeafter was complete.
<to be read again>
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also note that if you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks), as can be seen in Werner's edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: This probably means that you missed a `}` somewhere. Probably near a citation of `masaryk.1965a`.

Comment: I spent the day checking that. I didn't forget any }. In fact, the solution i found is to use \footnote{\cite...} instead of the simple \footcite.  But i would make me change every citation. could it be bibtex maybe?

Comment: @Angie: Without an MWE that's impossible to tell.

Comment: Second to @Caramdir's suggestion, I would sequentially comment out (or remove) lines of code until the problem is gone. Then edit them back in to hone in on the problem. Removing all the unnecessary stuff, if the problem still persists, post your MWE.

Comment: It's usually best to *make a copy of the file* and edit the copy- leave the original alone just incase things get worse during the de-bugging process.

Comment: {\blx@citepunct@i {\blxcitecmd {footcite}}{{}}{345{masaryk.1965a}}}. Alle\ETC Should fix it.